# Poll message from Kafka topic periodically(X interval) using kafka stream

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have kafka stream application running which will consume messages from topic whenever a new message posted to the listening topic.

```
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
streams.start();
```

I need to poll the topic periodically for new messages, from the documentation i tried setting the property "**poll.ms**" and value as 1 minute but it does not work.

Is there anyother way i can poll messages from kafka topic every X minutes.

Comment: Setting `poll.ms` is supported and should work. The config is logged -- can you double check the value? What do you exactly mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: Kafka Streams is designed to be continuous Stream processing (it is always polling). If you really want scheduled batches, perhaps you need a differerent tool, or change the mindset of the application logic?

Comment: for scheduling you can use Processor API, where Processor/Transformer save data in state store and Punctuator will periodically pass message  forward

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I mean it doesn't wait for interval set in poll.ms. As soon any record posted in topic it consumes.

Comment: Sure, that is how Kafka works. It's the same for the consumer. The configuration `poll.ms` is the maximum "blocking time" within `poll()` if _no_ data is available. It's not an interval when to call `poll()`. I guess you miss understood the config :)

Comment: Is there an answer for this question ? "Is there another way i can poll messages from kafka topic every X minutes. "